# Simple question in C++ function pointer

Tags: c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>

namespace enc = sensor_msgs::image_encodings;

void imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
{   cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;
    try
    {
        cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::BGR8);
    }

    catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
    {
        ROS_ERROR("cv_bridge exception: %s", e.what());
        return;
    }
    cv::imshow("OpenCV viewer uEye", cv_ptr->image);
    cv::waitKey(3);

}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "listenerKinectuEye");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    image_transport::ImageTransport it(nh);
    
    image_transport::Subscriber sub = it.subscribe("/camera/image_color", 1, imageCallback);

    ROS_INFO("subscribed to Kinect & uEye topics");
    ros::spin();
}
```

My question is how can I add a parameter to imageCallback function ? and how to use it in the subscribe (the Syntax) in the main function ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/165081/simple-question-in-c++-function-pointer/) by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on ROS Answers with karma: 751 on 2014-05-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 1):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[roscpp/Overview](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers) lookup the callback type. boost::bind is what you're searching for.

There is a lot of [questions](http://answers.ros.org/question/143196/class-send-through-a-callback-function/) about it here already

---

Originally posted by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) with karma: 1172 on 2014-05-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use the `boost bind` utilities for that. Here is a nice tutorial on how to go about that http://en.highscore.de/cpp/boost/functionobjects.html

---

Originally posted by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) with karma: 1295 on 2014-05-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1